# Was testing this code I found online but keep getting errors?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 


contract Courses {

struct Instructor {
    uint age;
    string fName;
    string lName;
}

mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
address[] public instructorAccts;

function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string memory _fName, string memory _lName) public {
    var instructor = instructors[_address];

    instructor.age = _age;
    instructor.fName = _fName;
    instructor.lName = _lName;

    instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
}

function getInstructors() public view returns ( address[]) {
    return instructorAccts;
}
}
```

I keep getting errors saying the var keyword is disabled and data location must be memory for return parameter in function, but none was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the compiler errors are fairly self-explanatory, but here's a fixed version:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Courses {
    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }

    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
    address[] public instructorAccts;

    function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string memory _fName, string memory _lName) public {
        Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address];

        instructor.age = _age;
        instructor.fName = _fName;
        instructor.lName = _lName;

        instructorAccts.push(_address);
    }

    function getInstructors() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return instructorAccts;
    }
}
```

- I gave a proper type to `instructor`.
- I gave a data location for `instructor`.
- I gave the return value of `getInstructors` a data location.
- I deleted the strange `-1` that wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to learn about data structures and mapping. But for some reason when I run this in remix I don't get any of the names or ages I listed. I just get the address.

Comment: Oops, I was confused between `instructors` and `instructorAccts`. Edited my answer to reflect that. `getInstructors` just returns an array of addresses, so yes, it's expected that you'll only get addresses back. If you want to make a function that returns something else, you can certainly do that.

Comment: thank you! I'ma play around with this code and see if I can update it. It's from 2017 apparently.